# How to add new value to dictionary [[String : String]]

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a dictionary, which looks like this:

```
var dict = [["number" : "1" ], ["number" : "2" ], ["number" : "3" ]]
```

Now I would like to add new value `"level" : "(number of level)"` to each index in my dictionary, and it should looks like that:

```
var dict = [["number" : "1", "level" : "one"], ["number" : "2", "level" : "two" ], ["number" : "3", "level" : "three" ]]
```

How can I add some value inside existing dictionary in this case?

Comment: Your 'dictionary' is actually an array of dictionaries, so you will need to loop through the array, retrieve the dictionary in each element and then just add the new key & value to the dictionary

Comment: @MikeVelazco wrong language

Comment: How do you know what level to assign?

Answer (score 3):

What you have listed as a dictionary is actually an array of dictionaries.  You can add an element to each of the directories by simply iterating the array.

You can use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the digits you have into equivalent words:

```
var anArray=[["number":"1"],["number":"2"],["number":"3"]]

let numberFormatter=NSNumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.numberStyle=NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle

for i in 0..<anArray.count {
    if let numberString=anArray[i]["number"] {
        if let number=Int(numberString) {
            anArray[i]["level"]=numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for i in 0...anArray.count-1` is so ugly... `for i in 0..<anArray.count` please ;)

Comment: Yeah.  I was still working on that. I don't really write Swift.

Answer (score 1):

As Paulw11 pointed out, you could use `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the digits to words:

```
let dictArray = [["number" : "1" ], ["number" : "2" ], ["number" : "3" ]]
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle
let mappedDictArray = dictArray.map { var d = $0; d["level"] = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number); return d; }
```

However, if you're interested in using the `level` key only for UI purposes, you'd be better writing a `Dictionary` extension, as there's no point is storing a redundant value:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func levelString() -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle
        return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(self["number"] as? Int ?? 0)
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
dictArray[0].level()
```